# Filepath of EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

I was following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764) to create a music player but have hit an obstacle.

I can load up the application all well and good. However, the list is not populated with any music files despite there being music files present in the "music" folder on my SD card inside my phone.

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

Where is the line of code Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; pointing to in terms of filepath?

I've looked it up online but have not found any information on this, just saying that it searches for music files in the external SD card, which is clearly not the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that everything was working and it was a silly oversight on my part.

The ListView was not visible in the phone's screen.